# Grouping test cases or "shared_examples_for" equivalent in specs2

Tags: scala, testing, tdd, bdd, specs2

I am trying to write a bunch of test codes against a Java class library and I am using specs2 on Scala.

I have a group of test cases that should be ran for all the subclasses of class T,
but could not figure out the best way to implement this.

Coming from Ruby, I naturally sought something like *shared_examples_for* macro as in Rspec, but there seems to be no such thing in specs2.

Then I thought, subclassing my own *Specification* subclass with test cases may be one way to go.

Is there any tidier solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an example of shared examples in the [User Guide](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Share+examples). Basically this uses the fact that you can define a method taking a specific instance to test and declare examples for it (see the `nonEmptyStack` method).

If this helps let me kickstart you with a quick example using a mutable `Specification`:

```
 import org.specs2._

 class SubclassesSpec extends mutable.Specification {
   "These examples must pass for all subclasses" >> {
     subclasses foreach { subclass => examples(subclass) }
   }

   /** @return instances of subclasses of type T where T is 
    * the supertype of the classes you want to test */
   def subclasses: Seq[T] = ...

   /** @return examples parameterized by a specific instance */
   def examples(t: T) = {
     "this is the first example" >> {
       // use t here
     }
     "this is the second example" >> {
       // use t here
     }
   }
 }
```

The only thing you need to check before you do that is the possible side-effects between examples. In the specification above, all the examples are executed concurrently *and* they share the same object. If that creates any issue, you can either:

- add `sequential` at the top of the specification to avoid concurrency
- change `subclasses` and `examples` to `def subclasses: Seq[() => T]` and `def examples(t: () => T)` so that you will create a brand new instance for each example

Comment: I don't see the point of pass-by-name on `examples` here. Where you trying out for the side-effect guards you mentioned later, but then backed out and forgot to remove it?

Comment: This isn't working for me. Should the return type of `examples` be `Fragment`? I get: Error:(40, 13) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.specs2.main.CommandLineAsResult[Unit]
  "#status" >> {

Comment: This has changed with specs2 3.x. You need to use the `Fragments.foreach` method now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not specs2, but ScalaTest has such syntax:

http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_tests